# Not getting any images in the PDF for jspdf function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image-processing, jspdf

I am new to development and am getting this error on clicking the button download images in reactjs.

I am getting a blank pdf on clicking download images.

[image]

This is my function in the react above the aclass

```
pdfGenerate = () =>{
     var doc=new jsPDF('landscape','px','a4','false');
     var base64Img = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty-monitoring- 
     dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926?alt=media&token=61399a02-1009- 
     4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4';
     
     doc.addImage(base64Img,'JPEG',65,20,500,400)
     doc.save('CQMS_IMAGES.pdf')
     
  }
```

I want the image to be generated in the pdf however nothing is coming.

This is my button:

```
<Button style={{float: 'right'}} color="primary" size= "sm" onClick= 
              {this.pdfGenerate}>Download Images</Button>
```

What am I doing wrong. Please help

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but the problem is with the URL you are using for the image. Actually, the URL is not giving the image in any of the image formats. I think it's the base64 encoded image. If you will try to download the image by going to that URL you will see that no file extension will appear if you would download the image. You will have to explicitly write the file extension when you will try to download the image this proves that the URL is not giving us the image in any valid image formats.
Try this one,

```
pdfGenerate = () =>{
         var doc=new jsPDF('landscape','px','a4','false');
         var base64Img = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty-monitoring- 
         dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926?alt=media&token=61399a02-1009- 
         4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4';
         
    var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ Base64.encode(base64Img);
         doc.addImage(imgData,'JPEG',65,20,500,400)
         doc.save('CQMS_IMAGES.pdf')
         
      }
```

if that does not work try this,

```
   pdfGenerate = () =>{
             var doc=new jsPDF('landscape','px','a4','false');
             var base64Img = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty-monitoring- 
             dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926?alt=media&token=61399a02-1009- 
             4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4';
             
        var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ base64Img;
             doc.addImage(imgData,'JPEG',65,20,500,400)
             doc.save('CQMS_IMAGES.pdf')
             
          }
```

PS: I am not sure about both. But you may try these.

Thanks.

Comment: It does not show any image.